# Do you know any good books, websites or tutorials for beginners in Visual Foxpro?

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

Do you know any good books, websites or tutorials for beginners in Visual Foxpro?

I haven't programmed in a while. I'm basically hacking into an old system made for our business and trying to upgrade it and add new functions.

I understand programming concepts. I just haven't sat down and produced any significant code in the past few years because I was working in a different field.

Oh and yes, I've googled and have a few pdfs. But recommendations from experts are always welcome so I can get started in the right direction.

I'm programming for business applications - accounting, inventory -- that sort of stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend having a look through the catalogue at [Hentzenwerke](http://www.hentzenwerke.com/) for books. Also subscribe to the VFP mailing list at [Leafe.com](http://www.leafe.com) is frequented by most of the gurus in the field.

Comment: Thanks. I know about Hentzenwerke but Leafe.com is new to me.

Answer (score 4):

The [Visual FoxPro Wiki](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~Foxite) and the [Foxite forums](http://www.foxite.com/) are the best places I've found for FoxPro information and to interact with experience FoxPro developers.

Answer (score 4):

Additionally, the 
[Universal Thread](http://www.universalthread.com)  is loaded with VFP experts...

Answer (score 4):

For ongoing advice, take a look at [FoxRockX](http://www.foxrockx.com), a bi-monthly magazine devoted to VFP.

Tamar

Answer (score 2):

[Learning Visual Foxpro](http://www.learningvisualfoxpro.com/) is referenced in [Links to blogs that have something to do with VFP, or by VFP folk](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~BlogWatch) but I wanted to call it out directly.

Comment: Any reason why you wanted to call it out directly?

Comment: Because it applies directly to the question "Do you know any good books, websites or tutorials for beginners in Visual Foxpro?", even though the asker may find other useful content on some of the other blogs referenced in the "Links to blogs that have something to do with VFP, or by VFP folk"

Comment: No, I meant what do you like about it? :) ... sorry, it wasn't meant to be sarcastic.

Answer (score 1):

I like http://www.tek-tips.com. It's a general site but it's got a forum for VFP and another for older versions.

Comment: Thanks...I couldn't find VFP at first, but then realized I was looking at the wrong category.